# Gradle groovy plugin's test is not picking up test resources

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, classpath

Probably a stupid question.

I'm writing a unit test for my gradle plugin. I understand that gradle custom plugin has `groovy` plugin applied by default, so `plugin/src/test/resources` will be included by default as my test resources.

Facts:

- Test class location: plugin/src/test/groovy/foo/bar/Test.groovy
- Test resource location: plugin/src/test/resources/foo/bar/**myfile**

I'm trying to access **myfile** from Test.groovy via

```
new File(this.class.getResource(".").toURI())
```

When debugging the above code resolves to this directory and **myfile** is not in there.

- plugin/build/classes/test/foo/bar

**myfile** can however be found at

- plugin/build/resources/test/foo/bar/**myfile**

Question: How do I access **myfile** from Test.groovy? Is this a standard behavior from groovy plugin?

**UPDATE**

What I wanted to get in my original use case was the directory because I have multiple resources (it was lost in the translation to this SO question). It seems like the resource is resolved correctly when I specify myfile like what Peter says. So:

- new File(this.class.getResource(".").toURI()) --> plugin/build/**classes**/test/foo/bar
- new File(this.class.getResource("myfile").toURI()) --> plugin/build/**resources**/test/foo/bar/**myfile**

I was adopting this hack before finally fixing it with explicit resource names: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64887#c13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.`, use `myfile`. If that doesn't help, try `getClass().classLoader.getResource("foo/bar/myfile")`.

Comment: `myfile` works. Btw my original use case was however to get the directory resources/test/foo/bar.